# Getting NullReferenceException unless I expand base class object while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.mac

First off, I'm using Xamarin Studio 6.1.3 in case that makes any difference.

I'm creating a simple app and want a login form to appear as a sheet. I followed the Xamarin tutorial for creating sheets (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-dialogs/#Creating_a_Custom_Sheet) but am running into an issue.

Per the tutorial, I have created a class:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using AppKit;

namespace SampleProject
{
  public partial class UserLoginController : NSViewController
  {
    private NSViewController _presentor;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return TxtUsername.StringValue; }
        set { TxtUsername.StringValue = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return TxtPassword.StringValue; }
        set { TxtPassword.StringValue = value; }
    }

    public NSViewController Presentor
    {
        get { return _presentor; }
        set { _presentor = value; }
    }

    public UserLoginController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    private void CloseDialog()
    {
        Presentor.DismissViewController(this);
    }

    partial void BtnCancelClick(NSObject sender)
    {
        RaiseDialogCanceled();
        CloseDialog();
    }

    partial void BtnLoginClick(NSObject sender)
    {
        RaiseDialogAccepted();
        CloseDialog();
    }

    public EventHandler DialogAccepted;

    internal void RaiseDialogAccepted()
    {
        if (this.DialogAccepted != null)
            this.DialogAccepted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public EventHandler DialogCanceled;

    internal void RaiseDialogCanceled()
    {
        if (this.DialogCanceled != null)
            this.DialogCanceled(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }


  }
}
```

And I have added an override for PrepareForSegue in my ViewController class:

```
    public override void PrepareForSegue(NSStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

        switch (segue.Identifier)
        {
            case "UserLoginSegue":
                UserLoginController loginSheet = segue.DestinationController as UserLoginController;
                loginSheet.Username = ""; //This line throws NullReferenceException unless I set a breakpoint and expand loginSheet.Base before allowing this line to execute.
                loginSheet.Password = "";
                loginSheet.Presentor = this;
                loginSheet.DialogAccepted += (object s, EventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine("OK Clicked"); };
                loginSheet.DialogCanceled += (object s, EventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine("Cancel Clicked"); };
                break;
        }
    }
```

See the comment in the above code block. I basically set a breakpoint on that line and when it triggers, I inspect the loginSheet object. If I expand the Base object to inspect it and then continue execution, everything works as expected. If I don't, I get a NullReferenceException whenever code tries to access any fields/properties/methods in the UserLoginController class.

I am completely baffled as to why this is happening. I set a breakpoint in the constructor of UserLoginController and verified it is being called with a handle and that the base constructor should be called as well.

I've read through the tutorial several times and don't see anything that I'm missing. Can't seem to find anybody else having the same problem.

My ultimate question is: What can I do to make the code work as expected?

For the sake of learning (which may shed light on the problem): What is going on behind the scenes when I inspect the base object of my UserLoginController class while debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that I need to check the `View` property of my `UserLoginController`.

I added the following line:

```
var theView = loginSheet.View;
```

and everything works as expected. I have yet to dig into the `View` property to see what it is doing behind the scenes that makes everything work.

Here is the modified, working `PrepareForSegue` override method:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(NSStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

    switch (segue.Identifier)
    {
        case "UserLoginSegue":
            UserLoginController loginSheet = segue.DestinationController as UserLoginController;
            var theView = loginSheet.View;
            loginSheet.Username = "";
            loginSheet.Password = "";
            loginSheet.Presentor = this;
            loginSheet.DialogAccepted += (object s, EventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine("OK Clicked"); };
            loginSheet.DialogCanceled += (object s, EventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine("Cancel Clicked"); };
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "If this property’s value is not already set when you access it, the view controller invokes the loadView method. That method, in turn, sets the view from the nib file identified by the view controller’s nibName and nibBundle properties." - https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434401-view?language=objc

Comment: With this new found information I was going to call LoadView() instead of checking the View property but according to Apple documentation for LoadView (https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434405-loadview?language=objc) - "Do not call this method. If you require this method to be called, access the view property." The link has more information on why it's bad to call the LoadView method directly.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand an object in the debugger, all properties not marked up with certain attributes are read via reflection so that we can display them in the IDE.

Maybe one of those properties has a side effect? You should be able to reproduce the effect using reflection, then bisect the property list to see who's effecting your behavior.

Comment: While talking it over with a colleague today the thought of reading everything via reflection crossed my mind. I'll give it a try and let you know what I find. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Using reflection allowed me to find the culprit. I posted an answer with the details. Thanks again for the advice.